# how to run package manager as i am not able to run it and an error is shown

Tags: package-management, error-handling

[image: this is the error shown when i log in to my home screen]

can i get any stepwise solution for this error
i am new to ubuntu and i have no idea to solve this issue
this started when i installed openshot through command terminals displayed in this page http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-openshot-under-debian-ubuntu-linux/
i have followed all the steps and after the installation i got this error currently i am using ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error shown in the above screenshot would be caused mainly because of incomplete installation of packages. So fix all the incomplete package installations by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```